# How to include path inside bashrc in linux for envirnment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Im testing my code for automation of the installation of a software

In bashrc file below:

```
# User specific aliases and functions

export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-9.0.1
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk-9.0.1/jre
export SCALA_HOME=/opt/scala-2.13.0
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk-9.0.1/bin:/opt/jdk-9.0.1/jre/bin
```

Here im trying to add $SCALA_HOME/bin to PATH.

this is the required output:

```
 `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk-9.0.1/bin:/opt/jdk-9.0.1/jre/bin:/opt/scala-2.13.0`

`sed -i '1n;/^export PATH/i\export SCALA_HOME=/opt/scala-2.13.0' .bashrc`
```

the above code worked to append SCALA_HOME above path but for appending in the same line im not able to do

```
`sed -i "s/\"export PATH\":.*,$/\"export PATH\": \":$SCALA_HOME/bin\",/g" .bashrc
sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unknown option to `s'`
```

please help me get the correct sed command to append SCALA_HOME in the PATH

Comment: It's because the SCALA_HOME value will contain slashes: choose a different delimiter for the `s///` command.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. Can you show exactly what the bashrc file is supposed to look like after your transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:
`sed '/export PATH/ s/$/:\$SCALA_HOME\/bin/' .bashrc`

Comment: if you are happy with the output add the -i option to change it in the file

Answer (score 0):

```
's/\(export PATH=.*\)/\1:\$SCALA_HOME\/bin/'
```

To go through your expression:

```
s/\"export PATH\":.*,$/\"export PATH\": \":$SCALA_HOME/bin\",/g"
```

The `\"export` will look for `"export` in your file. Why do you expect a double quote before the export? It isn't there in the example. Likewise, `PATH\":` in the pattern will look for `PATH":` in the file. That double quote isn't there either. Your `,$` at the end of your pattern will also prevent it from matching anywhere.